# RollupJS gives 'Unresolved dependencies' warning when modules imported by Typescript's BaseUrl

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I am bundling a library written in TypeScript with RollupJs.
In the codebase, I am making some imports using Typescript's `BaseUrl` as follows.

```json
"compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": "src",
   // ... other configs
  }
```

```
// in SomeComponent.ts
import { Status } from 'types/status'
```

Here `types` folder is under the `src` folder so I can make this import without using relative paths thanks to `baseUrl` config.

Rollup bundles the package but with the following warning.

> (!) Unresolved dependencies
> https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency

I believe Rollup sees `types/status` as an external dependency although it is not. How can I make Rollup respect the `baseUrl` config?

Lastly, my Rollup config:

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve({ browser: true }),
      commonjs(),
      image(),
      typescript({
        tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
        exclude: ['**/__tests__', '**/*.test.{ts,tsx}', '**/*.stories.tsx'],
      }),
      postcss({ modules: true }),
      copy({
        targets: [
          { src: './src/styles', dest: 'dist/esm' },
          { src: './src/styles', dest: 'dist/cjs' },
        ],
      }),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: 'dist/esm/types/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.css$/],
  },
];
```

Comment: I stumbled to this same problem today. But it looks like I get the error only when importing type, not from components. Using relative paths fixes this but I would like to know the root cause and how to fix.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem, and that settings work for me.
tsconfig.json:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
          "components/*": ["components/*"],
          "themes/*": ["themes/*"]
        },
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "plugins": [
          {
            "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin"
          }
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true
      },
      "include": ["src", "src/custom.d.ts"],
      "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
    }
```

I define here paths:

```
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["components/*"],
      "themes/*": ["themes/*"]
    },
```

And add them in compilerOptions for dts.
And also add rollup-plugin-includepaths lib for correct path for images.

```
import MOBILE_LOGO from 'components/auth/AuthPageContainer/assets/mobile_logo.svg';
import LOGO from 'components/auth/AuthPageContainer/assets/logo.svg';
```

My rollup.config.js:

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import esbuild from 'rollup-plugin-esbuild';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import includePaths from 'rollup-plugin-includepaths';
import packageJson from './package.json';
import tsconfigJson from './tsconfig.json';

const config = [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    external: [
      ...(Object.keys(packageJson.dependencies) || {}),
      ...(Object.keys(packageJson.devDependencies) || {}),
    ],
    plugins: [
      includePaths({ paths: [tsconfigJson.compilerOptions.baseUrl] }),
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve({
        main: true,
        browser: true,
        preferBuiltins: false,
      }),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({
        tsconfig: './tsconfig.build.json',
        declaration: true,
        declarationDir: 'dist',
      }),
      image(),
      esbuild({
        minify: true,
      }),
    ],
  },

  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
    external: [/\.css$/],
    plugins: [
      dts({
        compilerOptions: {
          baseUrl: tsconfigJson.compilerOptions.baseUrl,
          paths: tsconfigJson.compilerOptions.paths,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
];

export default config;
```

Hope, it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still wonder if there is any way to do it other than adding those into 'paths' field. There might be lots of folders in src that I want to import(other than components, themes in your example). Adding them one by one doesn't seem best solution for me.